# default argument promotion

Tags: c

```
main(){
  printf("%d %d",1234.5);
}
```

output: 0 1083394560

This is the case of default argument promotion where float variable is treated as double and then first `%d` displays 0 and other one displays the value of rest 4 bytes i.e. 1083394560.

My question is if `%d` reads first 4 bytes then how does this program

```
main()
{
  printf("%f",1234.5);
}
```

gives the right output. Because float is also of 4 bytes, it should also behave like `%d`.

Comment: i mean to say the 2nd pseudocode shud also give the output 0.

Comment: the output of following program :
main()
{
printf("%d %f",4.0,4.0);
}
output: 0 0.000000
why the above output is displaying but I expect it to be
0 4.000000

Comment: You can't make assumptions like "because it is also 4 bytes, it should behave the same".  Some calling conventions put floating point arguments in *different places* from integer/pointer arguments, or pad the arguments in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? `%f` can "know" that a `float` passed as a vararg argument has been promoted to something bigger (`double`) and act accordingly, of course. The code for `%d` does not know that it should expect a promoted floating point value; it expects a (suitably promoted) `int`.

Comment: ok if it is then tell me in the following program:
main() {
printf("%d %f",4.0,4.0);
}
output is: 0  0.000000
why?

Comment: @som Even though it is UB, you can think about it. `4.0, 4.0` has a certain representation on the stack - it is `00 00 80 40 00 00 80 40` as floats resp. `00 00 00 00 00 00 10 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 40` as doubles. `%d` takes the `00 00 00 00` so that `%f` gets the `00 00 10 40 00 00 00 00`, which is `5.31017013e-315` and treated as `0.0` of `%f` output.

Comment: how come the value is 5.31017013e-315 ?

Answer (score 1):

The `%f` format string takes a `double` value in the argument list, and prints it out. Since un-suffixed floating point literals are `double`s in C, and that doubles are not promoted or otherwise changed by default promotion rules, there is no magic at all happening with your second example.

Your first example is undefined behavior, anything could happen.

C99 §7.19.6.1 *The `fprintf` function*

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> [...]
>
> If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You answer your question by yourself:

> This is the case of default argument promotion where float variable is treated as double

Of course, `%f` knows about this default argument promotion and only deals with `double`s, not with `float`s.